# NodeJS - no response on request on port 8080

Tags: node.js, post

I've written a small server in Nodejs, its a supplementary server for a bigger which is running on the same machine.
The "master" server handles different requests then this "supplementary" server.

The "master" server is listening on port 80 while the "supplementary" server is listening on port 8080.

If I try and access the "supplementary" server like so:

http://172.31.16.218:8080/

I do get the homepage, but when I try to access:

http://172.31.16.218:8080/update_highscores

I get an error "page could not be displayed"

Here me my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require ('mysql');
var winston = require('winston');

var app = express();
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: '12345678',
    database: 'project_eclipse',
    port: 3306 });

    connection.connect(function(err){
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected ... \n\n");  
    } else {
        console.log("Error connecting database ... \n\n");  
    }
    }); 


// instruct the app to use the `bodyParser()` middleware for all routes

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.post('/update_highscores', function(request, response)
{

    var usr = 'user1';
    console.log('update_highscores searching for user:  ',usr);

    connection.query ('SELECT user_id FROM eclipse_users WHERE username=?', [ usr ], function(err, rows, fields) {

      if (!err)
      {
        response.send('got user id back');
      }
     else
     {
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
        response.send('ERROR - server error was encountered - please try again later'); 
        connection.end();}
        });
});

app.listen(8080,"127.31.16.218");
console.log('Server running at http://127.31.16.218:8080/');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this be because `app.post()` only defines a route for a HTTP POST request and navigating to a page in the browser normally will send a HTTP GET request?

Comment: @MikeTunnicliffe It certainly could be.

Comment: @KevinB Just read through the doc, it does seem like this could well be the reason.

Comment: @MikeTunnicliffe
Your'e right, that's what happens when you copy-paste code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just going to the URL `http://172.31.16.218:8080/update_highscores` in the browser, that would be a GET request, not a POST request so you would need an `app.get()` or an `app.all()` route to handle that.  Your `app.post()` route will only catch requests that are actually POST requests.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's what happens when you copy-paste code.